# Why is test-path returning $false for a PSDrive?

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'm connecting a PSDrive from a machine running SCCM and trying to do a test-path to work out whether or not to create a given directory.
However test-path is returning `$false` for directories that do indeed exist (as a matter of fact I can even tab-complete the paths in the PoSh window)

My PSDrive connection code is as follows:

```
New-PSDrive -Name $SiteCode -PSProvider CMSite -Root $ProviderMachineName -Scope global
```

This returns a PSDrive as "RED" which returns a `$true` result:

```
PS C:\> test-path RED:\
True
```

However when I try and test anything below that it returns `$false` and if I try and create the new-item it fails

```
PS C:\> test-path RED:\Driver\Dell\WinPE\
False
PS C:\> new-item RED:\Driver\Dell\WinPE\
new-item : Path already exists.
At line:1 char:1
+ new-item RED:\Driver\Dell\WinPE\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (OBFUSCATED\Driver\Dell\WinPE\:String) [New-Item], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Path,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

(I've obfuscated the FQDN of the machine)

This is what I get if I run a `get-item` on the path:

```
PSPath                : AdminUI.PS.Provider\CMSite::OBFUSCATED\Driver\Dell
PSParentPath          : AdminUI.PS.Provider\CMSite::OBFUSCATED\Driver
PSChildName           : Dell
PSDrive               : RED
PSProvider            : AdminUI.PS.Provider\CMSite
PSIsContainer         : True
SmsProviderObjectPath : SMS_ObjectContainerNode.ContainerNodeID=16777240
ContainerNodeID       : 16777240
FolderFlags           : 0
FolderGuid            : 1DAF9853-75BE-4629-97EF-0689D9E02961
IsEmpty               : False
Name                  : Dell
ObjectType            : 25
ObjectTypeName        : SMS_Driver
ParentContainerNodeID : 0
SearchFolder          : False
SearchString          :
SourceSite            : RED
```

I tried specifying `CMSite::` while running `test-path` and that didn't help either.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong to trip this up?

Comment: Could you please define `a machine running SCCM`?

Comment: I think he means a Windows Server OS.

Comment: @notjustme sure - it's a Windows Server 2019 machine which is running Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager.

Comment: Is the PSDrive listed with `Get-PSDrive`?

Comment: @T-Me sure is, otherwise I don't think I'd be able to run any of the commands above.

Comment: What powershell version do you use? I don't have the argument `CMSite ` for `New-PSDrive -PSProvider`

Comment: PSVersion                      5.1.18362.628
PSEdition                      Desktop

Comment: I don't think you'll have CMSite as it's provided by the SCCM Console install

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of whether it was ConfigMgr console on `random machine` or on the actual site server but I dunno, maybe that's old stuff and won't make much a difference these days - I rarely fiddle with SCCM anymore.

Comment: @notjustme I have tried this both locally on my machine and on the SCCM server itself, both return the same result.

Comment: Gotcha - made sense to me to ask and make sure.

Comment: what happens if you did this `Test-path AdminUI.PS.Provider\CMSite::OBFUSCATED\Driver\Dell` or `New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "AdminUI.PS.Provider\CMSite::OBFUSCATED\Driver\Dell" -Name "WinPE"` ???

Comment: @Vad The `test-path` still returns false.
Sorry if I wasn't clear but the `new-item` isn't a problem I was just using that as context to prove that the directory did indeed exist.

Comment: Hmm may be you must try `Test-path` with key "-Path" or "-LiteralPath"

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried `-path` `-literalpath` and even `-pspath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to this turned out to be super simple in the end.

Deleting the trailing slash appears to have fixed it:

```
PS C:\> test-path RED:\Driver\Dell\WinPE\
False
PS C:\> test-path RED:\Driver\Dell\WinPE
True
```

I'm not sure exactly *why* this is however.

Comment: For anybody curious on why the trailing slash is an issue, I'm fairly certain it's because "folders" in SCCM aren't exactly the same thing as we see in something like Windows Explorer. Folders in SCCM were an added functionality due to user demand, so it was jammed in and made to look and act like folders, almost... For example, the recurse option isn't available. Folders in SCCM are actually just Database notations, and work off NodeID's and container Nodes. The CMSITE PS-Drive provider adds a lot of options we're familiar with, but it's a fancy coating over chicken-wire and duct-tape.